# displays the data for the last 3 months available in the table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following invoice data :

tbl_invoice :

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | no_inv |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-01-02 | INV1   |
| 2015-01-02 | INV2   |
| 2013-01-01 | INV2   |
| 2021-01-05 | INV4   |
+------------+--------+
```

I want to display the last 3 months of data available even though it is different for different years, because my expected result is the last 3 months of data.

My Expectation Result :
In the invoice table from this figure, only date data are available in April 2020, May 2019 and June 2015.
I want to get the data for the last 3 months. How can SQL get results according to my expectations?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your date column is a datetime type, you can do this with a simple where.

You need to calculate the date 3 months ago, and filter to where date is greater than that.  e.g.:

`WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);`

See the datetime arithmetic functions here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

Solved with :

SELECT date
FROM invoice
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 3

Comment: If you're going to use group by, you should use an aggregate function in the select - e.g. `SELECT MAX(date) ...`.  MySQL gives unpredictable results if you don't, and most databases won't even let you select non aggregated and non grouped columns.

You should also include year, otherwise january 1964 will come before february 2021.

`SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(date), MONTH(date)) FROM invoice GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: There is no problem in sql for which the above is a 'solution'